# How to add new custom categories for work item states in azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019, devops-services

I want to create new categories for work item states in azure devops . Also is that possible to create a new workflow and map that new categories to the new workflow. Thus creating an entirely new workflow and categories in Azure Devops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to add custom categories as shown below, I am afraid this is currently not supported in azure devops . We can only add custom states but not custom categories .

[image]

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: okey. Thankyou . is it possible to create new workflow for workitems? @Hugh Lin - MSFT

Comment: You can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-workflow?view=azure-devops).

Comment: From this article iam getting the knowledge that we can only customise the existing workflow & we cannot create an entirely new workflow

Comment: Yes, currently we cannot add a entirely new workflow, we can only customize an existing workflow.